# Relation between vertex chromatic number and vertex connectivity.

Tags: graph-theory

I have an interesting question which I know its solution; And it's No! But I want to know that if there is any other counter examples else than complete bipartite graphs for it or not?

The question is as follows:

Is it true that for every graph $G$, one has $\chi(G)\ge \kappa(G)$? Prove this or provide a counterexample.

Where $\chi(G)$ stands for vertex chromatic number and $\kappa(G)$ stands for vertex connectivity; which is the minimal number of vertices such that if we remove them from our vertex set, then our connected graph will be divided in to disjoint components.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other counterexamples _than what?_

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't know that complete bipartite graphs are not satisfying in the condition of the question! Thanks to @Aravind, Now I will change the content of the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph

Answer (score 1):

Consider a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: Oh yes! you are right. I never thought about complete bipartite graphs! Thanks! But now if you let me I want to change the content of the question a bit.

Comment: @nikita.Popov Why do you want another example ? You can always take a sufficiently big complete bipartite graph so that $\kappa(G)>3$ and add an edge to your complete bipartite graph. It will always have chromatic number $3$.

Comment: @H.Potter, I was thinking that I have a new example in graph theory which I can expand it! But I understood that it is just a 3-partite  graph (not complete). I think we can have many examples in $k-$partite graphs for it?

Comment: @nikita.Popov Well, any $k$-colorable graph is $k$-partite, so $G$ is always $\chi(G)$-partite. Since, you want $\kappa(G)>\chi(G)$, $\chi(G)$ will be rather small, hence, the graph of your example will be bipartite or tripartite. And since $\kappa(G)$ will tend to be big, your $k$-partite graph will be close to a complete $k$-partite graph.

Comment: @H.Potter, yes, my example which I have found is a tripartite graph and very close to a complete tripartite graph. Thanks a lot! you explain very well. But my example has a very beautiful pattern and I was wonder that can I have a new generation of tripartite graphs which is somewhere applicable or not?